# How to get "value" attribute from a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable that holds the following value -

```
    $content = "<input value="" name="field" type="text">";
```

Using this variable in need to get the value of "value" attribute. How to get that ?

Comment: Your code is invalid! Check strings

Comment: @DarkBee that is wrong since the variable is a string and not a jQuery object.

Comment: @silentw : Unsure bouth that actualy. His syntax is off in the first place

Comment: @DarkBee you're correct, but I assume that it is a string...

Comment: Here $content is the output of jQuery.html() function. So it is considered as a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Dom Should be.

```
$content = '<input value="" name="field" type="text">';
```

Try This:

```
$(content).attr("value")
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FghD/)**

Comment: @user3121571:Check now. also modify the dom stored as variable.

Comment: See my original code snippet looks like this -                    var content  = jQuery('.row td.order').filter(function(){
  return jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text())==orderValue
               }).next().html();                                     And now variable 'content' has whatever input textbox i have given above. Using this I need to extract "value" attribute's value.

Comment: @user3121571:would be great if you can create a fiddle

Comment: i cannot recognize what are you trying to do in fiddle(usind filter function ).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$content = '<input value="" name="field" type="text">';//replace double quotes here with single quote
$(content).val();
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FghD/1/)